# Magento2: model cart do not load quote items on home page

Tags: magento2, cart

I create my custom theme with some custom module, on home page I tried to get all cart items (from quote) to create my custom mini cart, this is my block:

```
<?php

namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Block;

class Cart extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Url $catalogUrlBuilder,
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $customerSession,
            $checkoutSession,
            $catalogUrlBuilder,
            $cartHelper,
            $httpContext,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function getCartItems()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
        $cartModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $productsObject = $cartModel->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

        $cartItems = array();
        foreach ($productsObject as $item) {
            $cartItems[] = $item;
        }

        return $cartItems;
    }
}
```

I add this block on my `default.xml` but when I'm on home page, category pages or on product page the object quote is always empty. While on checkout pages, on customer pages I can see the cart items if they have added.

The strangest thing is that, if I disable the cache, the quote object works fine everywhere, while with cache enabled I get the quote empty.

Here there is my `<Vendor>\<Theme>\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> <update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
<body>

    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.messages" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="zopim-chat" template="Magento_Theme::head/zopim.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer  name="header.container">
        <container name="top-header" label="Page Header" as="top-header" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row no-margin">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::header/prodotti-header.phtml" name="prodotti-header" before="-"/>
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" template="Magento_Theme::header/logo.phtml" name="logo">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo.png</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">314</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">94</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::header/header-links.phtml" name="header-links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
        <container name="panel-header-row" label="Panel header" as="panel-header-row" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row no-margin">
            <block class="<Vendor>\CategoryList\Block\CategoryList" name="tree-category" template="<Vendor>_CategoryList::treeCategory.phtml">
                <block class="<Vendor>\CategoryList\Block\Category\Search" name="category-search" template="<Vendor>_CategoryList::category/search.phtml"/>
            </block> <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::header/panel-header-hide.phtml" name="panel-header-hide"/>

            <container name="panel-header-right" label="Panel header right" as="panel-header-right" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col s4 m4 l4 light2-grey panel-header right-panel">

                <!-- HERE I PUT THE CART BLOCK BY REFERING THIS CONTAINER -->

            </container>
        </container>
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::navbar.phtml" ttl="3600" after="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
    <container name="page-footer" label="Page Footer" as="page-footer" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer no-margin no-padding white black-text">
        <block class="<Vendor>\User\Block\FetchWishlistLogin" template="<Vendor>_User::fetchAddToWishlist.phtml" name="fetch-wishlist-login" before="-"/>
        <container name="newsletternewsletter" label="News Letter" as="newsletter" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row no-margin dark-grey">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::footer/newsletter-footer.phtml" name="newsletter-footer" before="-"/>
            <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" template="Magento_Theme::footer/newsletter-email.phtml" name="newsletter-email" after="-"/>
        </container>
        <container name="pre-footer" label="Pre footer" as="pre-footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row no-margin light2-grey">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::footer/pre-footer.phtml" name="rassicurazioni"/>
        </container>
        <container name="footer-info" label="Footer" as="footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row no-margin footer-info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="footer-col-1" template="Magento_Theme::footer/footer-col-1.phtml" before="-"/>
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="footer-col-2" template="Magento_Theme::footer/footer-col-2.phtml" after="footer-col-1"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="footer-col-3" template="Magento_Theme::footer/footer-col-3.phtml" after="footer-col-2"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="footer-col-4" template="Magento_Theme::footer/footer-col-4.phtml" after="-"/>
        </container>
    </container>
</body></page>
```

Then in `<Vendor>\<Module>\view\frontend\layout\default.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="panel-header-right">
        <block class="<Vendor>\Cart\Block\Cart" before="-" template="<Vendor>_Cart::cart-panel.phtml" name="cart-panel"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body></page>
```

#### Preconditions

1. Magento 2.1.2
2. Centos 7.2
3. PHP 5.6
4. MySQL 10.1.14-MariaDB

Comment: could you please post your layout file ?

Comment: @KeyurShah I post my layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just shoot in the dark, I think for cache you can try below solution

```
<block class="<Vendor>\Cart\Block\Cart" before="-" template="<Vendor>_Cart::cart-panel.phtml" name="cart-panel" cacheable="false" />
```

I have just added `cacheable="false"`, in your block file.

Comment: Yes, It works! You save me

Comment: Glad to hear that it works for you @3tech-AlessandroStaffolani

Comment: @KeyurShah, Is there any other way except "cacheable false"? Because it prevents the whole page from caching which affects the site speed.